# What anamoly arises when there is a primary key and unique key in a table of database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

What anamoly arises when there is a primary key and unique key in a table of database?
i want to know that is that primary key and the unique keys are two different things?
actually this question was asked to me while taking an interview..

Comment: Why would there be an anomaly exactly? A primary key can be an automatically generated ID. It is still possible to add one or more unique keys to the same table afterwards. 

Imagine a table with a userid column that is a primary key, and uses an IDENTITY column to have the DB generate values. You could still have unique keys on Email or social security numbers.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the "anomaly" the interviewer was referring to is from the normalization rules for relational databases. You can find rules lots of places, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), but I bet he was talking about "insertion anomaly", "deletion anomaly", and "update anomaly."

Assuming that, then an update anomaly could occur if you only update the records with the unique key instead of the primary key (because there could be more records in other tables perhaps). I'm not sure, but if you review those rules you might have a better answer yourself.

Comment: I think the first sentence of the first paragraph is the correct issue here. At least, that's what I would ask during a job interview for an entry level position.

Answer (score 0):

Of course both are different.

**Primary Key** uniquely defines each rows of the table. It can't be null. And there can be only one primary key(it might be simple or composite).

**Unique Key** states that, that column must contain unique value. It may contain null. There can be as many columns with unique key constraint.

Primary Key= Unique Key + Many other constraints.

Hope its clear to you.

Comment: suspect you meant "there can only be one primary key" above.

Comment: @MJB that's the catchphrase of "primary keys: highlander the movie"

Comment: @MJB: Yeah exactly. Sorry for the typo error.

Comment: Unique Constraint: "set of columns" rather than "column" (and there is no Unique Key, there is Foreign Key ;-) )

Comment: Ok Arioch "columns" not "column" :). Secondly the column or columns(as per you) with a constraint 'UNIQUE' is called as Unique Key :P.

Answer (score 0):

A **primary key** is an **unique key** with the added constraint that the key cannot be NULL. From a design point of view the primary key has for purpose to identify a row in your table. Other unique key just "appends to be unique" but shouldn't be used to "identify" a row (and just *can't* when NULL is allowed).

Now, speaking of an "anomaly" when a table has both keys is, well ... more questionable ?!?
In fact, this is a quite common case. Maybe the question was about a "discrepancy" between querying by the primary key vs querying by an unique key -- because of the possible (multiple rows having) null value in the later case?